# Message: Undefined variable: ver

Tags: codeigniter

i'm making a product crud in codeigniter but i have this problem with my code:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: ver

Filename: views/productos_view.php

Line Number: 51

Backtrace:

File: C:\wamp64\www\catalogo\application\views\productos_view.php
Line: 51
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\wamp64\www\catalogo\application\controllers\Welcome.php
Line: 23
Function: view

File: C:\wamp64\www\catalogo\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_onc

Welcome.php

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *  - or -
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('productos_view');
    }
}
```

Controller function

```
//controlador por defecto
public function index(){

    //array asociativo con la llamada al metodo
    //del modelo
    $productos["ver"]=$this->productos_model->ver();

    //cargo la vista y le paso los datos
    $this->load->view("productos_view",$productos);
}
```

Model

```
public function ver(){
    // //Hacemos una consulta
    $consulta=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM catalogo;");
    // Devolvemos el resultado de la consulta
    return $consulta->result();
}
```

Comment: You have to load your model. Either in your constructor if its going to be used in many functions(methods) in your controller or just in the index if that's the only place you will use it.

Answer (score 0):

see Mr. TimBrownlaw explanation, try add this code on you controller,

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('productos_model');
}
```

put on top index function

```
public function index()
{
$ver = ''; //Declare blank variable
$productos = array(); //Declare blank array
$ver = $this->productos_model->ver(); //get from model

$productos["ver"] = $ver; //assigne in $productos array

//cargo la vista y le paso los datos
$this->load->view("productos_view",$productos);
}
```

and can you show productos_view code?

Answer (score 0):

Repalce your code in Welcome controller with the below code.

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
   public function index() {
        $productos["ver"] = array();
        $this->load->view("productos_view",$productos);
     }
 }
```

Because you are not sending $ver in your welcome controller.